# How to populate a subcategory based on category

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a form where subcategory is decided on basis of category but  both category and subcategory are being fetched from database.
Earlier when database is not involved in it I used javascript populate method for the same where data is dummy
so i am trying to include the code for fetching subcategory from database in the same.
Here is my code uptill now

```
      <label>Job Category*</label>
      <?php
         $dataset =  $objCmn->getCat(); \\for getting category from database
            ?>
      <select id="jb-category" class="form-control" name="jb_category" onchange="populate(this.id, 'sub-category')" required>
         <option>Choose Category</option>
         <?php
            foreach ($dataset as $key => $cat) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $cat['maincategory_name'] . '">' . $cat['maincategory_name'] . '</option>';
               
            }
            ?>
      </select>

      <label>Sub Category*</label>
      <select id="sub-category" class="form-control" name="sub_category" required>
      </select>
```

function for populating the subcategory on base of category

```
function populate(s1, s2)
{
var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
s2.innerHTML = "";
var categoryValue = s1.value;
alert(categoryValue);
document.writeln(categoryValue);
<?php  $category_name  =  "<script>document.writeln(categoryValue)</script>"; 
           
             $categoryName = $objCmn->getSubCategory($category_name);
             foreach($categoryName as $key=>$row)
             {
                 ?> 
var optionArray = ["<?php $row['cat_name'] ?>|<?php $row['cat_name'] ?>",]; 
<?php
   }
    ?> 
for (var option in optionArray)
{
var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
var newOption = document.createElement("option");
newOption.value = pair[0];
newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
s2.options.add(newOption);
}
}
</script>
```

Is there any other way then embedding the php code inside JS for the same .
Previous i have tried to close script tag before php tag and open the same after php closing tag but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way to do this is to get the identifier of the category that has been selected, send it to your php script via ajax, fetch it's corresponding subcategories, return them back to javascript and then populate your subcategory selection.

If you are not familiar with **AJAX**, [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) might be of some help.

You can also have a look at some jquery methods [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp);